# How can I free the sasquatch on the Icewind Pass?

Tags: kingdom-rush

In *Kingdom Rush*, one of the achievements is:

> #### Like a Henderson
>
> Free the sasquatch on the Icewind Pass.

When I load the map, I see the sasquatch and I can click on it, but the option to free him never seems to be enabled:

[image: Icewind Pass sasquatch]

How do I enable it so I can free him and complete the achievement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to melt the ice with your Rain of Fire ability first.

Then you will be capable of summoning the Sasquatch by clicking on the cave.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the rain of fire on the ice wall and then you pay 500 for the Sasquatch and he is very helpful when dealing with the yetis.

Comment: I don't see how this adds additional info.  You're just repeating what agent86 said.

Answer (score -1):

Use rain of fire on the cave's entrance and then pay 400-500 gold to summon the Sasquatch.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the rain of fire to melt the ice trapping the Sasquatch. Then he will be free, defending for you.

Comment: But first pay 500 dollars first

Answer (score -2):

First, you need melt the cave with the Rain of Fire. Afterwards, you can pay 400-500 gold to summon him. Only 1 Sasquatch can be enabled at a time, but he can be summoned multiple times. He is great at dealing with melee enemies, but Shadow Archers, because of their ranged attack, and JT, because of his Insta-Kill capabilities, are not easily hindered. I put Barbarians around Sasquatch with the axe throwing ability to protect against archers.